# Commands for Installing Unity on Ubuntu Minimal Desktop

Tags: unity, installation, ubuntu-minimal

I want to know what to put in the terminal to install Unity DE on Ubuntu 11.10 minimal. For example.`Sudo apt-get install (whatever goes here)` Including the dependencies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*This answer is for older (before 17.10) versions of Ubuntu. See the answer by Gravity10 for later versions.*

---

This will give you a more "minimal" install. apt-get default behaviour is to install all recommended packages.

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: I'm aware it is 1.5 years later, but thank you so much for this command, I was googling quite a bit for this. Weeeh.

Answer (score 2):

### For Ubuntu 18.04+

Assuming that you went with Ubuntu Minimal to minimize your bloatware, you should run

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

This generally keeps all bloatware from installing. Run

```
sudo apt-get purge [PACKGE-NAME]
```

on any leftover packages you don't want. From what I've seen, there aren't any packages that really warrant this, but it's useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: It will only install the desktop environment? It won't install unnecessary programs?

Comment: Define "unnecessary" See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems

Comment: this will install *all* the bloatware